# Computer Network and design analysis

Tags: http, sockets

How do I Make a request to my server from a browser on a different machine. I'll need to be on the same network, and know the IP address of the machine that
is hosting my server.

Comment: Very strange question.. you answered yourself. Just write the url in the address bar using the address of that machine http://ipaddress/path/to/resource

Comment: yes just put the IP address in the address bar in the browser. If the browser doesn't automatically do it, or if the port isn't 80, you might need to write `http://the.ip.addr.ess:port/`